# loop through mysql table and save to text file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `user_details` this table has got morethan 100k user details

its index is `username`. I want loop through index(username) and save to a text file enclose with `<li>` tag (ex: `<li>mathew</li>`) by only 10k user names per each file.

the content of text file must be:

```
<li>mathew</li>
<li>john</li>
<li>ethan</li>
<li>kenan</li>
<li>brandon</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, name FROM user_details");

$nr = 0;
$i  = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $nr++;
    if ($nr >= 10000) {
        $nr = 0;
        $i++;
    }
    $data = '<li>'.$row[0].'</li>'."\n";
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/usernames-'.$i.'.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: What about looking up some PHP references?

Comment: I am not getting a proper idea from it...one is how do I store 10k each and second is filenames for each files

Comment: So you started with my example already and it worked?

Comment: yeah it is working and storing but it keep going not yet stopped

Comment: and line breaking isnt happening its kind of non wrap mode

Comment: Powtac thank you for this code anyway at least the basic concept is worked. I want to see how to break 10k files and line formating...